# How can I change the 'xticklabels' on barplot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to make a barplot with seaborn, and I was able to display all the data, but the xlabels are invading the other ones space, like you can see on the image down.

I tried to change the barplot properity to `['M01_V',...' '...,'M05_A', ...' '... ,'M015']`, but it remove the datas from chart that aren't on the list.[image]

The expected result are the xlabels equal to the heatmap labels, but I cant use xticklabels properity like on the heatmap. How can I change the xlabels?

Comment: you can rotate xticks `plt.xticks(rotation=90)`

Comment: Could you please show us a small example code how you create the plot? See e.g. [mcve]